# Rotate kivy widget

Tags: python, rotation, kivy

I have a layout scheme more or less like this:

```
#at build:

float_layout_1 = FloatLayout()
box_layout_1 = BoxLayout()
box_layout_2 = BoxLayout()
float_layout_2 = FloatLayout()
self.image = Image()

float_layout_2.add_widget(self.image)
box_layout_2.add_widget(float_layout_2)
box_layout_1.add_widget(box_layout_2)
float_layout_1.add_widget(box_layout_1)

return float_layout_1
```

I want to rotate just the Image widget, when I call a function do rotate the image, everything rotates:

```
#at a internal class method
with self.image.canvas:
    Rotate(angle, a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another rotation after your widget that rotates by the inverse amount, or enclose the widget canvas in `PushMatrix` (before) and `PopMatrix` (after) instructions.